# How can I prevent the text from flickering in Chrome in Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS in VMware Workstation Pro 15?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, display, vmware-workstation, kubuntu

The text is sometimes from flickering in Chrome in Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS in VMware Workstation Pro 15:

[image]

How can I prevent that?

I don't have this issue with Firefox.

Environment:

- Hypervisor: VMWare Workstation Pro 15.0.0
- Host: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate
- Guest: Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. VMware extension pack installed, guest was installed via VMware EasyInstall.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent the text from flickering in Chrome in Kubuntu
> 20.04.4 LTS in VMware Workstation Pro 15?

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in VMware V16 on a supported host and there is no flicker at all.

(1) Try a trial version of VMware V16 to see if that helps.

(2) Update the Video drivers in your host machine.

(3) Update your host to a Supported Operating System, use VMware V16.2.3 and that should solve your issues.

All works well, Windows 10 or Windows 11.

Comment: Thanks, point taken, I'll upgrade everything in the near future.

Comment: I think you will be happy once done.  I did test Chrome in Ubuntu and it was no problem. So you should be fine.